# Online javascript documentator for online scripts

Tags: javascript, documentation-generation

I'd like to use my existing javascript on our production server to create docs when I need them.  I comment all my code, I'd prefer to not install anything and use it online.

If it splits the comments to the left and puts methods on right that'd be cool.

I tried yuidocs but that didn't work at all and not wanting to trial and error a bunch of npm stuff.

Can I write something simple for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ExplainJS
Instant side-by-side view of your comments and code.

http://www.explainjs.com/

Found this by randomly searching someone's twitter feed. :)